# Choosing DNS server to add A records remotly

Tags: dns, bash

I need to write a script that adds some A records to DNS server dynamically to mimic a real DNS zone. My questions are what DNS server to choose, bind9 dnsmasq and how to add A records to those servers?

Comment: For the howto part you've picked the wrong SE site. Bind supports this, as IMHO does Unbound. So if we shall recommend you a DNS server, we'd need a few more details on your requirements: What OS should it run on? What specific features do you need? Is there a price limit if it comes to paid solutions?

Comment: If you don't have much invested in BIND already I'd look at PowerDNS or this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I choose to use dnsmasq and add address=/hostname/ip to it's configuration remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Happy bind9 on Debian user here.

To drag this closer to on-topic if you want to update/manage DNS for a single domain just using the zone files is fine.  If you will end up managing several and you aren't a real *nix admin then I'd look at setting up a management interface.  As far as those go, ISPConfig is good and the how-tos on setup/configuration/etc. that are on howtoforge (all written by the same team) go very well wtih it.